# How to compare comma separated string in one column with the comma separated strings other dataframe

Tags: r, stringstream

I have two df as below
df1:

```
    M1     |
    -------+
    a,b,c  |
    a      |
    b,c    |
    c,b,a  |
    b,a,d  |
    d,a,b,c|
    a,d,c  |
    b      |
    c,d    |
    d,a    |
```

df2:

```
X1      |X2
--------+---
a       |1
b       |2
c       |3
d       |4
a,b     |5
a,c     |6
a,d     |7
b,c     |8
b,d     |9
c,d     |10
a,b,c   |11
a,c,d   |12
a,b,d   |13
b,c,d   |14
a,b,c,d |15
```

can someone help me to match values in df1$M1 and df2$X1. and put the corresponding X2 value in column M2 as below

df1:

```
M1      |M2
--------+---
a,b,c   |11
a       |1
b,c     |8
c,b,a   |11
b,a,d   |13
d,a,b,c |15
a,d,c   |12
b       |2
c,d     |10
d,a     |7
```

Can someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X1` and `M1` have to be stored as Characters. You can check with `str(df1)`, and re-assign if necessary `df1 <- as.character(df1$X1)`, and the same for `df2`

Then, create new columns with the values in alphabetical order:

`df1$Ordered <- sapply(lapply(strsplit(df1$X1, ","), sort),paste,collapse=",")`

`df2$Ordered <- sapply(lapply(strsplit(df2$M1, ","), sort),paste,collapse=",")`

Then perform a join like so:

`merge(df1, df2, by="Ordered")`

If you want to include all the values in `df1` regardless of whether they have a matching value in `df2`, add the `all.x = TRUE` argument. Same logic applies adding `all = TRUE` (include everything from both data frames), or `all.y = TRUE` for `df2`.

Comment: Have a close look at `d,a,b,c` = `a,b,c,d`

Comment: i want a solution so that it is independent of sequence of values around commas
if df1$M1[6] is d,a,b,c
it should give value of df1$M2[6]  as 15 i.e. df2$X2[15] corresponding to df2$X1[15] (a,b,c,d)

Comment: @aman I revised my answer to reflect that by creating a sorted version of each column to join on.